# Unable to Create HIVE table in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a HIVE table in Apache Spark using Databricks.

I am using the following code:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testdatabase.testtable

AS

SELECT
*
FROM location '/mnt/mylocation'
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
extraneous input ''/mnt/mylocation'' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 7, pos 14)

== SQL ==
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testdatabase.testtable

AS

SELECT
*
FROM location '/mnt/mylocation'
```

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but you need to change syntax - instead of `location` use format (it's described in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-names.html#table-name)):

```
<file_format>.`<location>`
```

For example:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testdatabase.testtable
AS SELECT *
FROM delta.`/mnt/mylocation`
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this answer. I will try this later before accepting as answer - although I'm sure it will work

Comment: yep, I've tested it on the "full version"

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe VIEWS support specifying a Data Source in the SELECT query.

[CREATE VIEW Spark 3.0.1 Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html)

I believe only TABLES support the [location keyword](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html).  Keep in mind that creating a Hive "Table" is just a pointer to the files when you specify the location path.

Changing this to a `CREATE TABLE` statement and specifying the schema should work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE testdatabase.testtable (
 col1 INT,
 col2 STRING,
 ...
)
USING PARQUET
LOCATION '/mnt/mylocation'
```

If you just want something ephemeral, you might read this in as a DataFrame and then [register a temp table](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView).

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/mylocation')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('testtable')
```

Now you can use `default.testtable` in SQL cells.

Comment: it works on Databricks, just need to use another syntax. I believe that it should work in Apache Spark as well